pyinstaller add a PATH to extracted rundir before running
I add binaries to my pyinstaller --onefile by just adding them to pwd:
--add-binary="/dist/bin/rancher:." --add-binary="/dist/bin/kubectl:."
But the rancher binary only accepts kubectl without any path. so it must find kubectlin the path:
20240627155655.188|INFO|namespaces.py:497|execute: /tmp/_MEII1tHGc/rancher kubectl 
get pods --namespace=test12-keycloak-server-production --output=json

20240627155655.211|CRITICAL|namespaces.py:150|kubectl is required to be set in your path
to use this command. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/ for more info. 
Error: exec: \"kubectl\": executable file not found in $PATH

I add a prefix updating the PATH to all execution:
20240627171653.205|INFO|namespaces.py:509|execute: export PATH="/tmp/_MEINq0MXK:$PATH";
rancher kubectl get pods --namespace=test12-operator-portal-web --output=json

Is it possible to add this path automatically in pyinstaller config?
